# Ceil number to the nearest non zero thousand

Tags: php

I have random product prices that i need to ceil to the nearest multiple digits ,,

Below are more samples

320 --> 500
8,890 --> 1,000
13,200 --> 13,000
89,300 --> 90,000

193,897 --> 194,000

Basically I want all product prices to have either 000 at the end or 00 at the end ,

i tried `echo  round(4389,-2);` but that didn't provide desired results.

```
echo  round(4389,-1); echo "<br>";
echo  round(4389,-2); echo "<br>";
echo  round(4389,-3); echo "<br>";
echo  round(4389,-4); echo "<br>";


echo  round(213,-2); echo "<br>";
```

How can i achieve this with php ?

Comment: `8,890 --> 1,000` and 
`13,200 --> 13,000` is two complete different scenarios, is this a typo?

Comment: `8,890 --> 1,000` - I don't understand... Unless that's supposed to be 10,000?

Comment: `13,200 --> 13,000` this is not a ceil...

Answer (score 1):

The function round() can be used to calculate the nearest thousandth of an integer.
499 must first be added to the integer.

```
$data = [320,8890,13200,89300,193897, 1000, 1001];
foreach($data as $val){
  $ceil1000 = round($val+499,-3);
  echo $val.' -> '.$ceil1000.'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
320 -> 1000
8890 -> 9000
13200 -> 14000
89300 -> 90000
193897 -> 194000
1000 -> 1000
1001 -> 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what formula you are looking for, but this is the adaptions of your code to get the result that you desire in the examples given.

```
echo  round(320, -2) .    " - 500 <br>";
echo  round(8890, -2) .   " - 1000 <br>";
echo  round(13200 ,-3) .  " - 13000 <br>" ;
echo  round(89300 ,-4) .  " - 90000 <br>"; 
echo  round(193897 ,-3) .  " - 194000 <br>";
```

> Returns the rounded value of val to specified precision (number of digits after the decimal point).

The second argument to `round()` is the optional number of decimal digits to round to.

Comment: round(13200 ,-3) --> 13,000 , i need this to be 14,000. Using round will need me to check for the value and apply the precision controller accordingly,, i wondering if there is a more elegant solution...

Comment: @salimsaid, for that use this: `echo (ceil(13200/1000) * 1000)`. The "1000" comes from the desired nearest digits. However in your example you said `13,200 --> 13,000`.